# Android ImageButton without Padding

Tags: android, sdk, onclick, padding, imagebutton

Currently my imageButtons display an image with a very undesirable padding around them. How do I get rid of the padding and just have the image as the button.

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/defaultbutton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/defaultbutton2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Secondly, How do I add links to these imagebuttons to open in the browser `onClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<ImageButton android:background="@drawable/defaultbutton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageButton android:background="@drawable/defaultbutton2" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

As for part 2 of your question... open what in your browser? Open a random URL? If so...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Open a URL in the browser by clicking the button.  But another question, currently the buttons are stacked on each other, I want them to be side by side, which view/layout would I put them inside to have them be side by side

Comment: You really should take a look at some of the layout docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html are probably good ones to read. You're looking for a LinearLayout with orientation set to horizontal though.